# Is it safe to use Fody.PropertyChanged with MVVMCross Or it is down the performance of app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, fody, fody-propertychanged

Today I read about new plugin on net which **Fody.PropertyChanged** which is very simple and easy to use.

Currently I am using MVVMCross where we have to call **RaisePropertyChange(()=>Property)** again and again. Is it safe to use **Fody.PropertyChanged** with MVVMCross. Any One have experience of that I also watch this example of using MVVMCross and Foody.RaisePropertyChange

https://github.com/slodge/BindingTalk/blob/master/BindingTalk.Droid/ViewModels/FodySimpleViewModel.cs

Or Is there any solution in MVVMCross from which we get rid from using RaisPropertyChange() again and again

Thanks,

Best Regard

Comment: - What you conclude with all answers, have you integrate Fody with MVVMCross ? If Yes share your experience.  Fody works for all kind of properties or work only specific type of properties i.e. string only ?

Comment: I used in one of my projects and its working good, recommended to all

Comment: Fody works for all kind of properties or work only specific type of properties i.e. string only ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fody.PropertyChanged should not be any slower than manual calls to `RaisePropertyChanged`. What Fody.PropertyChanged effectively does is write that code for you at compile time.

So, you don't have to type all those messy `RaisePropertyChanged` calls, and you don't have to see them either, making your code much cleaner. But if you look at what gets compiled (using ILSpy or a similar program), you will see that they've all been automatically added for you. So, from a performance standpoint, there should be no difference, but it makes your code easier to write, easier to read, and easier to maintain.

I'm a huge fan of Fody.PropertyChanged. I've been using it for years now with MVVM Light (which I believe is similar MVVMCross), and I've never found it to be the cause of a slowdown. I definitely suggest you give it a try.

If you are using version control (which you should be), commit your project, install Fody.PropertyChanged, get rid of all those `RaisePropertyChanged` calls, and watch the magic happen. If you don't like it, you can always go back to your previous version.

Comment: Thanks @devuxer. Let me check then I mark this as answer. I hope mvvmcross should not be disturbed by this.

Comment: @devuxer : Can Fody works for all kind properties ? As I experienced it works for string properties, but when we take with ObservableCollection or MvxCommand as property , fody not calls RaisePropertyChance internally for this. We need to call it in our code manually. What you say about it ? Kindly correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 4):

As @devuxer said, Fody.PropertyChanged won´t slow down performance. It won´t cause any more processing than the RaisePropertyChanged(() => ...) because that´s exactly what you get when compiling the app, nothing else. 
You can see exactly how it works in the [readme file](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)

I use Fody everywhere in my MvvmCross apps. Models, view models, etc

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    // every property will notify changes
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class ChatMessage
{
    public string Uid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SentAt { get; set; }
    public string SenderConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

**Note**: If you add [method binding](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding#rio) to the mix, you will get rid of tons of boilerplate code. I don´t use a single Command in the whole app

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[DoNotNotify]** attribute to exclude a property or type from having notification injected, or  injects **[DependsOnAttribute]** property to be notified when a dependent property is set.

more info:
https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged